# why explicit specialization of a friend function is allowed?

Tags: c++, templates, friend, specialization, friend-function

As a general rule, explicit specialization is allowed on a namespace scope.
The following code:

```cpp
template<typename T>
class B {
        template<typename U> void test(T) {};
        template<> void test(int) {};
};
```

make g++ produce the following error:
`error: explicit specialization in non-namespace scope`

At the same time, friend function template specialization is one of two possible ways to make friend function templates work inside class templates.
The following code works like a charm:

```cpp
template<typename T>
class B; 

template<typename T>
void test(B<T>);

template<typename T>
class B {
        friend void test<>(B<T>);
};
```

At the same time, the following does not compile, giving the same error as for the Snippet one:

```cpp
template<typename T>
class B {
        template<typename U> friend void test(U);
        template<>friend void test<B<T>>(B<T>);
};
```

My questions are:

1. Why friends are getting this kind of special treatment (would appreciate a reference to a standard);
2. What is this wicked sintax for full specialization anyways? Snippet: `friend void test<>(B<T>);`

**EDIT 1**
Fixed syntax errors in snippet 1.

Comment: _"make g++ produce the following error"_ no it doesn't, it's "error: variable or field 'test' declared void".

Comment: This is a known gcc bug. For the first part [Explicit specialization in non-namespace scope does not compile in GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49707184/explicit-specialization-in-non-namespace-scope-does-not-compile-in-gcc)

Comment: For the latter part of the question: [An explicit specialization cannot be a friend declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27767117/an-explicit-specialization-cannot-be-a-friend-declaration)

Comment: @PasserBy Thanks for an observation! Syntax fixed, now it does.

Comment: @user12002570 Thanks for the references! So, as I understood, the main problem with allowing friend **definitions** for a specialization is that it may be hard to resolve situations when this function is instantiated somewhere else before the class it is friend to is. And it will lead to violation of ODR that is hard to manage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you fix the obvious syntax errors in your example:

Explicit specializations of member function templates are also allowed in class scope. This has been clarified a long time ago, but it is a defect report that GCC has never implemented (so far), see [GCC bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=85282).

However, a `friend` declaration may not declare an explicit or partial specialization. Doing that isn't really sensible, because the function (template) declared by the `friend` declaration belongs to the enclosing namespace scope, not the class scope.

As you showed, it is already possible to friend a specific specialization of a function template. It doesn't matter to the `friend` declaration whether or not the specialization is declared as an explicit specialization, so there is no reason to allow it. You can declare the explicit specialization of the function template later at namespace scope, where it usually belongs for a non-member function template.

And while

```
friend void test<>(B<T>);
```

declares a specific specialization of the function template `test` to be a friend of the class, it isn't an explicit specialization declaration and doesn't declare that specialization of the function to be explicitly-specialized. The declaration only makes the function specialization a `friend`, but the primary template will still be used to implicitly instantiate a definition for that specialization.

On the other hand an explicit specialization declaration declares that no implicit instantiation from the primary template should be used for that function template specialization, but that instead the corresponding explicit specialization definition for that function template specialization should be used.

An explicit specialization can be clearly identified by its template head being exactly `template<>`, no other declaration is an explicit specialization and no explicit specialization looks different.

Comment: Seems like I got slightly confused by the wording at cppreference. So, the construct `friend void test<>(B<T>);` inside a class template is an explicit instantiation declaration, pretty much like an `extern template void test<>(B<T>);` at namespace scope?

Comment: @tntnkn No, it is not an "explicit instantiation declaration". That is a different thing entirely. Instead it is a friend declaration for a specialization.

Comment: @user12002570 Ah, so, it is like an explicit template specialization at namespace scope, `template<> void test(B<*whatever type*>);`? Both associate arguments with templates and both does not compile code?

Comment: @tntnkn Again no, it is also not like "explicit template specialization". It is a different thing. It is a friend declaration not a "explicit template specialization declaration". I know it might/can be confusing to beginners(specially coming across it for the first time). Note in the friend declaration here we don't write `template<>`.

Comment: @user12002570 Ah, right, cppreference says literally `An explicit specialization cannot be a friend declaration`. I got confused with gcc diagnostic for a friend "definition" for a specialization before that line poped in front of my eyes. Ok, so that is just a syntax that allows a friend to refer to a specialization that is generated when the class is instantiated?

Comment: @tntnkn Yes exactly *that is just a syntax that allows a friend to refer to a specialization that is generated when the class is instantiated*

Comment: @user12002570 That's a relief! Thank you kindly, good stranger!

Comment: @tntnkn For completeness: An _explicit specialization declaration_ or _explicit specialization definition_ is a declaration that starts with `template<>`. An _explicit instantiation declaration_ or _explicit instantiation definition_ is a declaration that starts with `template`, not followed by `<`.  Anything not looking like that is neither of the two. A `friend` declaration can't be either of the two.

Comment: @user17732522 I guess sometimes something that looks like a duck and quacks like a duck is not a duck at all!)